# Exporting SQL Database and DTU capacity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

When exporting a SQL Database to storage our DTU capacity is reached, which essentially means that our system performance is severely compromised.

[image: DTU Limit]

This is a problem for us as we use the export feature to backup and move our databases.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: With the new service tiers (that measure DTU) you have Point-in-time restore. Why you want to make backups (at application sensitive timeframe)? Also - why would you want to "move" database in an application sensitive timeslot?

Comment: @astaykov: We perform "versioned" backups during our release process.  These backups get restored to test and development environments. Point in Time restores are used for recovery purposes.

Comment: Do you use the automated export feature, or some 3rd party tooling (like RedGate's tools)?

Comment: @astaykov: I use the Export feature on the management portal.  I believe this is essentially what is behind the automated export.

Comment: if your DB is on Basic service tier, no wonder this is the case. If you use S1 or higher, this is warring a bit. What service tier do you use?

Comment: Using S2. Darabase is about 5Gb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today (Jan, 2015) situation is as follows:

Export feature was created before these new service tiers were introduced. In order to make transactionally consistent export, the process that is running in the background is making a lot of queries to gather database info. Then it continues to do a lot of queries until the data is fully backed up. Thus in a complex (and large) database no wonder maxes out the DTUs.

There are different approaches to solve this issue:

- Temporary upgrade to a higher service tier during the export
- Scale down when export is completed

OR even better:

- Use the point in time restore feature to restore a most recent copy to a **new** database.
- Export that new database (thus not affecting live application at all)
- Delete the **new** database

The latter will give you best performance and reliability.

** UPDATE (SEP 2016) **

As of today (or even earlier) all editions of Azure SQL Database do provide automatic backup and point-in-time restore. With this feature, you no longer need to make exports for the purposes of simple Backup. 
Check more on the [Azure SQL Database service tiers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/) page.

Database Export, as well as the built-in Back-up and restore do give the customer Transactionaly consistent databases.

Comment: It's a pity that this is the best way around this problem.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A point in time copy will not give a transactionally consistent copy of the database. Backup is one of the big weaknesses in SQL Azure.